# Amazon IAP Android PurchasingListener never called

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement a subscription IAP on Android using the Amazon SDK (3.0.3). I made all things as described in Amazon appropriate documentation and their sample app and configured Amazon App Tester properly. However have no luck, I am getting no responses from PurchasingListener.

The ResponseReceiver has following structure in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name = "com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver"
        android:permission = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I register PurchaseListener in onCreate():

```
PurchasingService.registerListener(this.getApplicationContext(), purchasingListener);
```

Then make this call in onStart()

```
final Set<String> productSkus = new HashSet<String>();
        for (final MySku mySku : MySku.values()) {
            productSkus.add(mySku.getSku());
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart: call getProductData for skus: " + mySku.getSku());
        }

        PurchasingService.getProductData(productSkus);
```

and finally in onResume():

```
PurchasingService.getUserData();
PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates(false);
```

Nothing from these call had returned any response. The Listener itself is registeres, as I can see in logs:

```
2022-07-27 18:50:14.791 11790-11790/......amazon D/d: Appstore SDK - Sandbox Mode: PurchasingListener registered: ......amazon.iap.SamplePurchasingListener@b3c6192
```

It is important to say, that if I am using old style receiver structure in Manifest (without "android:permission = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" under <receiver tag), like here:

```
<receiver android:name = "com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                android:permission = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

, I am getting some responses, but very frustrating, since it is not what is expected to be, and this permission is highlighted with err:

```
Protecting an unsupported element with a permission is a no-op and potentially dangerous
```

The logs in this case show:

```
2022-07-27 19:07:11.673 12723-12723/.....amazon D/e: Appstore SDK - Sandbox Mode: sendGetUserDataRequest
2022-07-27 19:07:11.684 12723-12723/.....amazon D/e: Appstore SDK - Sandbox Mode: sendPurchaseUpdatesRequest/sendGetUserData first:e0656912-440d-4c7d-a864-0548028a803d
2022-07-27 19:07:11.743 12723-12723/.....amazon D/e: Appstore SDK - Sandbox Mode: handleResponse
2022-07-27 19:07:11.895 12723-12723/......amazon D/IAPListener: onProductDataResponse: RequestStatus (SUCCESSFUL)
2022-07-27 19:07:11.897 12723-12723/.....amazon D/IAPListener: onProductDataResponse: successful.  The item data map in this response includes the valid SKUs
2022-07-27 19:07:11.897 12723-12723/...amazon D/IAPListener: onProductDataResponse: 0 unavailable skus
```

... and no other things are out there. Button for puchasing is dead and no other responses!

I don't minify the code with Proguard.

Testing device Amazon Fire 7 Tablet.

Target SDK - 32.

I stuck here for a long time, will be highly grateful if anyone could help me with this question!

Thank you in advance...

===========
Update 1:

On different testing devices the result is different. On Amazon Fire 7 Tablet all is dead. But on Xiaomi Redmi S2 PurchasingListener is alive but gives empty data for products. Here is the logs:

```
... D/IAPListener: onUserDataResponse: get user id (l3HL7XppEMhrOGDnur9-ulvqomrSg6qyODKmah76lJU=, marketplace (US) 
... D/IAPListener: onProductDataResponse: RequestStatus (SUCCESSFUL)
.... D/IAPListener: onProductDataResponse: successful.  The item data map in this response includes the valid SKUs
.... D/IAPListener: onProductDataResponse: response.getProductData(): {}
.... D/IAPListener: onProductDataResponse: 0 unavailable skus
.... D/IAPListener: onPurchaseUpdatesResponse: requestId (a5db322e-d894-4ebf-896a-9007140c91d2) purchaseUpdatesResponseStatus (SUCCESSFUL) userId ()
```

The same is on Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Comment: Can you confirm if you were able to get the `SampleIAPSubscriptionsApp` working on your device? That should help rule out if there's a configuration issue with Amazon App Tester.

Comment: Nope, Sample app for subscriptions is also doesn't work. I have also one app in Amazon Market with implemented IAP. I tested it before releasing with Amazon App Tester successfully. Now it doesn't work too.

Comment: It sounds like Amazon App Tester failed to find the IAP data. Can you confirm if the IAP json data is in the right place? Did you grant Amazon App Tester access to external storage? I don't have a modern device to validate, just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Of course, it tested very much times, json file is in right place and App Tester recognize it. I see it on appropriate section of App Tester interface. And if is not, I see dialog "There is no data" or something like that. can make a screenshot :)

If you will have time, could you kindly test App Tester yourself? Even their Example App doesn't work. If you could get it working we can confirm that at least it is working for you and I would be able to check this code and compare with mine, though I believe there must not be any difference.

Comment: I think App Tester itself is buggy. It is very old and seems to be didn't updated by Amazon. Will write them today directly.

Comment: I just tried `SampleIAPSubscriptionsApp` and it works on my phone (Android 9, API level 28), and Amazon App Tester version `3.0.200140.0_3023310`. Here is my log in case it helps. https://pastebin.com/RCHBy0Su

Comment: Also a friendly reminder to set your app to sandbox mode, which I believe you've already done.
`adb shell setprop debug.amazon.sandboxmode debug`

Comment: You may also want to check out this answer which affect API level 30+
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71224021/2072811

Comment: Many thanks!
Sure, I set up sandbox mode and even added venezia queries etc. Something goes wrong by me, don't know why.

Could you kindly send me this test project as is? I will test it at me side and compare codes. You can send to "mailbox@sargius.pro"

Comment: Here is the [project files and my debug apk](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/C2sSQABDLGoGl8m054uR1hVUD5oGovE2HGeIWpQ6vQc). I simply downloaded `Appstore_SDK_3.0.3.zip`, extracted `SampleIAPSubscriptionsApp` from it, then ran `gradlew installDebug` to build the apk. I did not make any local code changes.

Comment: Thanks for Support. I think I found the error! The code was ok, but I set all parameters in Amazon IAP Tester to their positive values. But they, short to say, must be tested separately. I think I will get iot working.

You can write some reasonable answer about this and I will Accept it :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you figured out the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, double-check the following:

1. Make sure `amazon.sdktester.json` is in the right location. Open Amazon App Tester, expand the "IAP Items in JSON File" section to ensure it can read your IAP items
2. As per your discovery, double-check the configuration in Amazon App Tester and reset everything back to default as needed
3. Set your app to [sandbox mode](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-app-tester-user-guide.html#installtester):

```
adb shell setprop debug.amazon.sandboxmode debug
```

4. Ensure [ProGuard is setup properly](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-obfuscate-the-code.html) (or temporary disable it to help isolate the issue)
5. Test with one of the IAP samples to isolate any configuration issue with Amazon App Tester. The sample apps should work as is without any modification (step 1-3 above is still relevant).

Hope that helps~